# How to start a thread only if it is not executing or not started before, or only one instance of thread should be created

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have the following method, that called every time I click over a button, this results to start a new thread again and again when the button is pressed, that results to multiple initialisation of thread, however I want only one thread should get executed, how can I achieve this.

```
    private void scheduleMessages() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
         //Some operations
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Note: this is a small method and I don't want to create a separate class, just to make it singleton, so a solution without singleton pattern will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe block this button until thread finish his job (or get interrupted)

Comment: you could try to assign the instance of the thread to some variable. Before you then restart a new thread in your method you can check if the variable already has some thread assigned with it or not

Comment: But do you want to execute every "click" or is the button "disabled" during the execution ? If you need to run every click, the used a [fixed thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) and submit every click in it (with one thread).
If not, the flag idea of Lukas works fine, but I would try to rewrite this to be thread safe, two thread could be execute if the `scheduleMessages` method is called twice before the first thread start.

Answer (score 1):

if you cannot make instance of this to check `isActive()` you should make a semaphore variable - a boolean, that you set to `true` when you start thread and set to `false` when you are done.

```
private void scheduleMessages() {
    if (!taskRunning){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               taskRunning = true;
               //Some operations
               taskRunning = false;
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI : It is not thread safe, you could simply synchronize the method and set `taskRunning = true` outside the `Runnable`.

Answer (score 0):

Have that thread be a background thread - maybe initialize it when the button is pressed the first time.

Have that thread listen to a queue - and act upon messages in that queue.

Whenever the button is pressed again, put a new message into the queue.

Answer (score 0):

If your need to execute every requests but on a specific number of threads, you can use a thread pool and let the executor manage the queue .

```
private ExecutorService services;
private final static int POOL_SIZE = 1;

public MessagesService(){
    services = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(POOL_SIZE);
}

public void scheduleMessages(Runnable r){
    services.submit(r);
}
```

If you call `addCall` x times, x thread will be executed at the end but will never use more than the number of thread available in the pool. Here, 1 thread.

---

For a system that only accept one request, you can use the same approch but check the `Future` returned by a single thread executor. That way, you can check the status of the service.

```
private ExecutorService services;
private Future<?> lastCall; 

public MessagesService() {
    services = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    lastCall = null;
}

public synchronized void scheduleMessages(Runnable r) {
    if(!isScheduled()){
        lastCall = services.submit(r);
    }
}

public boolean isScheduled(){
    return lastCall != null && !lastCall.isDone();
}
```

That way, the `Runnable` doesn't need to update a flag, which give a reusable solution.

Here is a sample of the `Runnable` to test these codes :

```
new Runnable() { 
    System.out.println("Running");
    try {
       Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```